# Equaling bounding box to another bounding box : Opencv , Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, opencv, bounding-box

I am trying to sort bounding boxes and in my algo I have a line in which bounding box of index j is equaling index j+1

```
 contourRects.get(j) = contourRects.get(j+1);
```

But it gives an error that left hand side can only be variable.

EDIT:

```
                int j;
                boolean flag = true;
                Rect temp;

                while(flag)
                {
                    flag = false;

                    for(j=0; j<contourRects.size(); j++)
                    {
                        if(contourRects.get(j).y < contourRects.get(j+1).y)
                        {
                            temp = contourRects.get(j);
                            contourRects(j) = contourRects.get(j+1);
                            contourRects.get(j+1) = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And one more thing contoursRect is a list

```
List<Rect> contourRects = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the f.f.g code:

```
Collections.swap(contourRects, j, j + 1);
```

Instead of:

```
 temp = contourRects.get(j);
 contourRects(j) = contourRects.get(j+1);
 contourRects.get(j+1) = temp;
```

Comment: I am trying to sort please take a look at question I have edited with code

Comment: It is sorting in descending order

Comment: Or maybe not sorting because contours were retrieved in that order

Comment: But did my answer help you?

Comment: It did help the cause